# Delphi XE7 Android Record with String Element won't compile

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

In Delphi FMX XE7, Win32, I have a record type:

```
type TSettingsRec = record
  SessionTimeOut: Word;
  EventString: String[50];
end;
```

When I change the Target to Android, I get a compiler error:

> [DCC Error] MainForm.pas(45): E2029 ';' expected but '[' found

I need to define the length[50] of the EventString element because the TRecord is actually being read from a database (Firebird) which was written  to the database by a Delphi 7 program using Bin2Hex (for a reason known only to the author of that program):

```
var
  rec: TSettingsRec;
  settings: string;

SetLength(settings, SizeOf(rec)*2);
BinToHex(@rec, @settings[1]), SizeOf(rec));
```

This I decode effectively in using XE7 (win32) using:

```
var
  rec: TSettingsRec;
  settings: String;

SetLength(settings, SizeOf(rec) * 2);
System.Classes.HexToBin(Pchar(settings), @rec, SizeOf(rec));
```

But this doesn't work, when I compile for Android. So how do I specify the length [50] of the EventString on the Android platform?

Comment: `EventString: array [0..49] of Char;`?

Comment: @Abelisto You missed the length byte, and also used the wrong element type. It should be AnsiChar or Byte.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nope. I just believe that platform  depended compiler must to use platform compatible types. If not - it is wrong compiler (assembler in other words)

Comment: @nolaspeaker Accept or reject the answer, we are all waiting for your decision!

Comment: @abelisto You don't understand what I said, or what the question is asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use short strings on the mobile compilers. You'll need to re-think the code. Perhaps like this:

```
type
  TSettingsRec = record
  private
    FSessionTimeOut: Word;
    FEventStringLength: Byte;
    FEventString: array [0..49] of Byte; // ANSI encoded
    function GetEventString: string;
    procedure SetEventString(const Value: string);
  public
    property SessionTimeOut: Word read FSessionTimeOut write FSessionTimeOut;
    property EventString: string read GetEventString write SetEventString;
  end;
```

This replicates the memory layout of the legacy short string. Which is a single byte containing the string length, followed by an array of length 50, of ANSI encoded text containing the payload. The record wraps the legacy layout with more natural properties, which make the type more readily usable.

Of course we still need to write those properties. Like this:

```
function TSettingsRec.GetEventString: string;
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Bytes, Min(FEventStringLength, Length(FEventString)));
  Move(FEventString, Pointer(Bytes)^, Length(Bytes));
  Result := TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(Bytes);
end;

procedure TSettingsRec.SetEventString(const Value: string);
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  Bytes := TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(Value);
  FEventStringLength := Min(Length(Bytes), Length(FEventString));
  Move(Pointer(Bytes)^, FEventString, FEventStringLength);
end;
```

This will work on Windows, but not on mobile compilers because `TEncoding.ANSI` has no meaning. So you'll need to create an encoding with the desired code page. For instance:

```
Encoding := TEncoding.Create(1252);
```

Do note that I've not even compiled this code, so it may have some wrinkles. But I think the concept shown here is the cleanest way to move your code forward. I'll leave you to work out the appropriate details for your setting.

Comment: I would guess because you were 6 minutes late? +1

Comment: I don't get the dv. I'd like to know if there is a glaring error so that I can fix it.

Comment: I don't understand the DV either. This looks like a well thought-out answer to me.

Comment: This looks good so far, but the decoding of the settings string is still unclear to me. Lets says I have const settings = ''0C00F40158021E000E30313B30323B30333B30343B303500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'; Where is the replacement code for System.Classes.HexToBin(Pchar(settings), @rec, SizeOf(rec));

Comment: @nolaspeaker In case you need to fill some record by the binary data, you have to use at least byte array. For example: `var a: TRecord; VBytes: array[0..SizeOf(TRecord)] of Byte absolute a;`

Comment: @nola The HexToBin and BinToHex code should work as is I believe

Comment: @Abelisto You are really not helping. You don't need to do what you said, and in any case your byte array is the wrong length.

Comment: @nola Your HexToBin and BinToHex work. The code in my answer works too. But the hex you included doesn't match the original code. There are more fields in your record. The length of your hex is too long. Count it and see. This hex would match your record: `0C000E30313B30323B30333B30343B303500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`. Note the length byte, `0E`. Your hex was clearly generated from a different record. The hex in this comment matches and has timeout of 12 and a string of `01;02;03;04;05`

Comment: To clarify, I mean that the record that you used to generate your hex has some extra members beyond those shown in the question.

Comment: Correct. I had abbreviated the record definition for the question (and forgot that I had done so) when I cut and paste the hex-string in haste this morning. Then the comment edit timeout died. Apologies.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. I don't know how to do the encoding. I don't actually understand what I'm encoding from, and to. Should I ask a separate question: "How to decode an ANSI string on Android?"

Comment: You need to know how the original data was encoded. I can't tell you that. I think I've done all I can.

Comment: You confused me with the "Encoding := TEncoding.Create(1252);" part of your answer. I am accepting the complete and usable answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the encoding, it depends very much on where the data comes from, how it was generated and so on. I'm assuming you are working with legacy data, otherwise you'd use UTF-8 when generating new data. And likely serialize as JSON.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76773/discussion-between-nolaspeaker-and-david-heffernan).

Answer (score 3):

`String[50]` is not supported on mobile platforms. That is a legacy data type known as a `ShortString`, consisting of 51 bytes of data, where the first byte is the length of the string and the next 50 bytes are 8-bit characters that define the string value.

The equivalent definition would be `array[0..50] of byte`, where the first byte defines the length of the actual data.  `byte` is used because the mobile platforms do not support `AnsiChar` (without a 3rd party patch).